# How can I prevent someone from creating a Firebase account through the console?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a new web-app that's connected with Firebase. Now, I know that javascript functions can be run from the console.

**Can I prevent someone from creating Firebase accounts?**

I can't disable email/password authentication as that would make my app unusable(people won't be able to log in).

The function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` can't be restricted as far as I know.

I've had one idea of a kind-of fix, but even that doesn't feel safe.

My idea is to restrict so the function can be called only by an authenticated user. I would restrict this on the front end since it can't be done through firebase.

I would then obfuscate the code so they can't change it and still have my authorization data.

Comment: You absolutely cannot trust the client. If an HTTP request can be made to your site, the client can make it no matter what you do. You can't even be sure that the client is a web browser.

Comment: Add some code with explanation, so that it will help us to give the proper solution.